# How long should registering as a Google Play developer take?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

As far as I can tell, it should be instantaneous after I make the payment on Google Checkout, which I did last night. There's nothing mentioning any delay in the documentation and the receipt message simply says to return to the Google Play Developer Site to finish my registration. However, clicking the link it gives just takes me back to the paying stage.

Is this kind of delay normal or am I just going to have to contact support or pay again and try to cancel the original?

Comment: I haven't hit this myself but it may be due to the form of payment - Did you pay by card / bank transfer / ??

Comment: I paid with my credit card via Google Checkout. I've used the same card and Google account for buying apps so, as far as I know, it should all work fine.

Comment: Hmm I would've expected that to be instantaneous too. I'm assuming the transaction is marked as complete in your Google Checkout pages?

Comment: Apparently it's not (I had looked at it but hadn't looked at any others, so I didn't know complete ones should have a tick and a reference to a credit card charge at the top). It does say that Google's "received the order" and that I should return to the site to continue registration, though. I'm not sure of anything that would be causing a delay with the credit card - every other order has the charge listed on the same date the order was made.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to track down why it failed/has been delayed - It might be worth checking with your bank. Good luck :) [Sorry, missed your edit - Cards _should_ be instant unless there are either funding issues or the transaction gets flagged as fraudulent. NB the payment process is actually 2-step - Your bank authorises the payment, then Google takes it. it's possible you're between the 2 in which case, you should get the money returned/re-credited to your account after a few days (at least with my bank)]

Comment: I tried buying something else with Google Wallet and that card (just an digital issue of a comic I was going to buy anyway) and payment completed within an hour. So if there's any problem, it's specifically with this charge...

Ah, well. I'll give it another day or so and then contact my bank or try it again if I have to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I signed up today, and clicking the link you have also clicked takes me to the developer console. There is a notice saying "Your Registration to Google Play is still being processed"; but I am able to upload APKs (I just can't publish them until the registration completes).

Comment: This is happening with me as well. Did you get it solved?

Comment: This is happening to my too. How long did it take?

Comment: Sorry, this is probably too late for the people who've asked but for anyone else wondering - I emailed Google Play developer support shortly after asking here and they sorted it out, though the whole process took about a week in total. They never actually told me what the issue was, so I assume it was something on their end rather than something I had or hadn't done.

Answer (score 5):

It can take up to 48 hours:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468

> Please note that the developer registration transaction may take up to
>   48 hours to process.

Good luck!

Comment: Waiting since 28/06/2013 :/

Answer (score 2):

I've created more than 30 accounts for my clients. It used to take up to 2 days for the account to be activated.

But, these days (since [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19)) it may take more time, sometimes up to 7 days.

Some countries will require more time to verify the address of the developer, other countries doe not require to verify address.

When you choose developer name at the beginning, you may be asked for ID verification ([source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-complete-your-account-details)) and this could take up to 1 month.

> Note: To process your request for a Play Developer account you may be asked for a valid government ID and a credit card, both under your legal name. If this information is determined to be invalid, your registration fee will not be refunded.

Also -from my experience- I've notice that the first app in the account will always take more time than updates or second app, it usually take from 2-7 days.